# Not enough storage to process this command excetion in CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection

Tags: c++, com, command-line-interface

I am working with Wpf c# and using a dependency project in managed c++. I have to create a bitmap from dicom file. I got 
"Not enough storage to process this command" exception in `CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection`

The piece of code is like this:

```
 bmpsou = safe_cast<InteropBitmap^>(System::Windows::Interop::Imaging::CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection( 
                            IntPtr(section), di->getWidth(), di->getHeight(), PixelFormats::Bgr32,di->getWidth() * 4, 0 )) ;
```

Can you please suggest any solution to resolve this issue

Comment: DICOM image files are usually large.  Which makes it very likely that the exception message is accurate.  Change the EXE project's Platform target setting to AnyCPU and you'll get lots and lots of memory.  Your C++/CLI project needs to be built to target x64.

Comment: Need a few more details; what are the values for di->getWidth & di->getHeight?